# RPC SERVER is unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2003, tcpip, rpc

windows 2003 is getting this error. restart the machine or just the network connection fix the problem.

date and time is the same one.
tcp/ip is started and running
remote registry is running

the changes made lately to the network is that the DC crashed and went to IT for restore and antivirus is not up to date because license issue (purchase delay)

what can be fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

RPC SERVER is unavailable means a request was made to a remote service (of some sort), and the remote service did not respond.  Often it's because the request was blocked by a firewall (possibly Windows firewall on the remote server), or the remote service that the request was sent to isn't running (or isn't listening for incoming requests).

It's hard to help much more without know what component is giving that error, and what remote service the component is trying to communicate with.

Answer (score 0):

If a DC crashed and was offline for a while, it's perfectly fine for a server (or any domain computer, really) to complain about its unavailability; that's especially true if you only have one DC (which you really shouldn't).

Since one of the protocols user by domain computers to talk to DCs is RPC, you will see several "RPC server is unavailable" in the event log (amongst all sort of other errors).